# Software recommendation tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm surprised no one brought this up before, but there are both [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) and [software-recommendations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) tags around representing the same thing.

Fix?

**EDIT**

Okay, found out too late that the latter redirects to the former. Can't we just merge them, so when the wrong one is used, it automatically corrects itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been done: [the plural is marked as a synonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/software-recommendation/synonyms) which means that you won't be able to create a question with [software-recommendations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) no matter how hard you try.

Comment: But still appears when you are about to type it out. Can it not be removed from there as well?

Comment: @Oxwivi - why would it be removed, it doesn't matter - even if you select the plural it'll still revert to the singular